# C++ Loops - inputting integers until user quits

Tags: c++, loops

well I'm trying to get the user to input an integers as much as they want, until they input a negative number.  1st step was to use the ATOF function to convert string to number(which I did), and then allow the user to input integers(I only manage to do once just to see if I can use the atof function correctly.

Any help/tips is appreciated on giving me the right direction.
Here is my code thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() { 
using namespace std;
char buffer[256];
char tempBuff[256] = {'\n'};
double result; 
int count = 0;

cout << "Testing " << endl;

cout << "Enter Any integers: ";
cin.getline(buffer,256);

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
{
    if(isdigit(buffer[i]))
{
    tempBuff[count] = buffer[i];
    count++;
}
}

if (atof(tempBuff) > 0) { 
result = atof(tempBuff) / 2;

}

cout << endl <<  "The integer you put was: " << tempBuff 
<< " And dividing the integers  "<< result << endl;

cin.ignore();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Homework time - Use the debugger - that is the appendix part of the lecture notes

Comment: Yeah, i'll keep reworking this code and experiment with using the other loops.

Comment: Your purpose is not clear. Do you want to input integers or digits? And what do you want to do with these, only divide each by 2? Or do you want to store them for later use?

Comment: (1)I wanted to enter a number  that I could  either omit the ',' as in 1000 or write some code to handle the ','.  (2)I would add each new input to the current sum(which I plan to implement) and divide by the number of those valid number inputs.  Sorry if I was not clear, and well, thanks for the replies, I think what caught me off guard was using the Atof function, then using strlen to test my number length.

Comment: Why not just type in the homework assignment as ask us "please do this for me". Or perhaps learn and use a debugger

Comment: Why are you using `atof` to input *integers*?  The `f` means floating point.  Did you want `atoi` instead?

Comment: @Ed.  I said in the topic "Any help/tips" appreciated.  I didn't say "any code input" appreciated.  If someone were to simply question my reasons of why I used this certain loop, or method, then I would take that as a help/tip.  Thomas wanted to convert string to double, was reading about it online on how to implement atof.

Answer (score 0):

How is `atof` supposed to know how many valid digits `tempBuff` contains? The `atof` function only accepts a C-style string as its input. Otherwise, it has no way to know how many characters are valid.

You can use `tempBuff[count] = 0;` before the call of `atof`. A C-style string is terminated by a zero byte.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will rework on this with the atof function.